# do an "abstract" loop in python

Tags: python, loops

Suppose I want to compute for `n`, print all `a_1  +a_2 + ... + a_n` where `a_i` are natural numbers less than `n`.

In the case `n` is "small" (for example `n = 3`), I use the following codes.

```
from itertools import product
n=3
for a_1,a_2,a_3 in product(range(n),repeat=n):
    print a_1+a_2+a_3
```

But if `n` is "large", say `n = 10`, I need type

```
from itertools import product
n=10
for a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9,a_10 in product(range(n),repeat=n):
    print a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7+a_8+a_9+a_10
```

If I want to compute `n = 100`, this type will be very terrible! Do we have any other method?

Comment: Doesn't a nested for loop work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't unpack the tuple:

```
for t in product(range(n), repeat=n):
    print sum(t)
```

By using a variable, you are implying you don't know how big the tuple will be, and therefore can't meaningfully unpack it. Your code will have to adjust accordingly.

Comment: I decided to delete my answer and move my content to your post. I believe it was a valid answer, but it was downvoted for whatever reason. Hope you don't mind the edit. You can roll back if you dislike it.

Comment: I do dislike it; there's no reason to obfuscate the code just to eliminate one line. The question is also more about iterating over a sequence of tuples of unknown length in general, not the particular body of the loop.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion.